# airmon-ng start wlan0 has no answer for Interface,Chipset, Driver

Tags: 12.04, virtualization

I run Ubuntu 12.04.5 on Oracle VM VirtualBox, when I type airmon-ng start wlan0 i get no answers for the Interface Chipset Driver, I just started using Ubuntu and i don't know if the problem is that I run Ubuntu on VM?

Consequently when I type airodump-ng mon0 I get that failed:no such device.

Answer (score 0):

To use airmon-ng from within a VM (assuming Virtualbox here..) you need to install the Guest add ons. Then you need to be sure you add your wifi device (it cannot be a built in device on a laptop), just use a USB one. then when you start the VM, be sure you can see the wifi device in network manager or `ifconfig` (from the command line). Assuming all is well, you should be able to start using airmon-ng now. After issuing the `sudo airmon-ng start wlan0` command, type `ifconfig` and verify you now have a mon0 device.

Comment: if i install Ubuntu as a regular OS, will I have such a problem by using airmon-ng?

Comment: nope, it comes with the aircrack-ng package in the repos. Used it myself.